# Maximum likelihood of sample mean

Tags: maximum-likelihood, sampling, mean

It is an easy computation to show that given some data sampled from the binomial, gaussian, Poisson, or exponential distribution, the MLE of the mean of the distribution is the sample mean. However, for the uniform distribution, this is not true (the MLE is the average of the maximum and the minimum of the data).

So, the question is: is there any sort of characterization of distributions for which the sample mean is the MLE of the mean?

Comment: I would guess exponential family distributions for which the sum of the observations is a sufficient statistic...

Comment: It would be nice to know if there were others -- there are certainly distributions where the median is the MLE but not a sufficient statistic, but I don't know about the mean.

Comment: @jbowman ChatGPT agrees with you

Comment: Nooooooo!!!!!!!!